# Not Getting Edit Text Data

Tags: android

I am New to Android . I don't know how to get the data of EditText in Android .

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity2">
   <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edOne"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edSecond"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code :

```
    val one=edOne.text.toString()
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
        val two=edOne.text.toString()
       Log.e("Tag",one +" "+two)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one is calling from onCreate() method . and at the time of creation of you onCreate() you don't have any data in editText one .So you can't get any data from one if you have not added from xml .

So just move your one code into click listener.

```
val one=edOne.text.toString()
btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
    val two=edOne.text.toString()
   Log.e("Tag",one +" "+two)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access related View elements with findViewById and use them later.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.EditText
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var edOne : EditText
        private lateinit var btnAdd : Button
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            edOne = findViewById(R.id.edOne)
            btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd)
            
            val one=edOne.text.toString()
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
                val two=edOne.text.toString()
                Log.e("Tag",one +" "+two)
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!!